# Text Repeat itself on button with space VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA and are few things I Don't really understand. I am trying to make a button that each time I press it a new form should be applied 2 cells underneath the original one, I managed to make the borders move with help of someone from StackOverflow but I can't make the text also reset as well.(I will upload, the file for you to see !)

The code:

```
Sub DoSix()
    DoBorders Range("A4:P9")
    Range("A4").Value = "Bought At"
    Range("B4").Value = "NR"
    Range("C4").Value = "Name of Stock"
    Range("D4").Value = "PB"
    Range("E4").Value = "PA"
    Range("F4").Value = "PR"
    Range("H4").Value = "Name"
    Range("I4").Value = "1"
    Range("J4").Value = "2"
    Range("K4").Value = "3"
    Range("L4").Value = "4"
    Range("M4").Value = "5"
    Range("N4").Value = "Data"
    Range("B5").Value = "1"
    Range("B6").Value = "2"
    Range("B7").Value = "3"
    Range("B8").Value = "4"
    Range("B9").Value = "5"
    Range("H5").Value = "Price"
    Range("H6").Value = "Price"
    Range("H7").Value = "Price"
    Range("H8").Value = "Price"
    Range("H9").Value = "Price"
End Sub
Sub ResetStart()
    DoBorders Nothing
End Sub
Sub DoBorders(rng As Range)
Dim useRange As Range
    Static lastRange As Range

    'handle resetting the "last range"
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set lastRange = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If lastRange Is Nothing Then
        Set useRange = rng

    Else
        Set useRange = lastRange.Cells(1).Offset(lastRange.Rows.Count + 2, 0) _
                                   .Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    End If

    Set lastRange = useRange
     With useRange
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'remove all borders
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

DL LINK:
https://mega.nz/#!wwdnlT6A!gxMKYwhjxlX1fjMXPWPhYbK-j-nAIiQ_VbZgdKqBJ-s

Comment: Please clarify two items: (1)  Your title says "text repeat itself on button with space" - does that mean you want the text appearing on the button to change, or do you mean "do something on button click"?  and (2) what exactly is "press it a new form should be applied 2 cells underneath the original one"? New form? Do you mean "add new rows"? and beneath what? The line between row 9 and 10, or add two rows beneath line 9, or ???

Comment: Hi Wayne, what I want to do is next: On each button press, a text should appear in some cells, if you press the same button again, the text should appear AGAIN, but few rows underneath the original cells(but in the same manner) Example: I press the button once, "PRICE" Appears in cell H5. I press the button AGAIN, now the price should appear in cell H13, then if I press again the button it should appear on cell H21 and so on.. I am not sure I make myself understood sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Wayne, a DL link of my excel file to understand better https://mega.nz/#!wwdnlT6A!gxMKYwhjxlX1fjMXPWPhYbK-j-nAIiQ_VbZgdKqBJ-s

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. Looking at your code, if you modify "DoSix" to use a relative row number, then I think that solves most of your problems. For example, the first click would start with row 4 and populate the cells. The next click would determine the last used row, add two as your 'blank rows', then populate the cells. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yep, thats exactly how I wish it would be possible... How to set that relative row number?

Comment: I'm away from my pc gor another hour and can give specific details when I get back. Briefly, you would determine last used row, add your two blank rows and run your code... which needs to use offsets rather than the hard references you currently have

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your existing workbook, then replace all your code with the code I provide below.  This will allow you to reference cells relative to the last used cell.  I added comments to the code to explain things that may look *weird*

```
Option Explicit         ' ALWAYS USE THIS!!!

Sub DoSix()
Dim lLastRow    As Long
Dim lLastCol    As Long
Dim rng         As Range

    ' If you start with an 'empty' worksheet, the LastRow check gives an error.
    ' So, just ignore the error and initialize the starting row number.
    On Error Resume Next        ' Ignore error for a second
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lLastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End With
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        lLastRow = 4
    Else
        lLastRow = lLastRow + 3
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Reference all the cells as relative to where you want to be
    DoBorders Range("A" & lLastRow & ":P" & lLastRow + 5)
    Range("A" & lLastRow).Value = "Bought At"
    Range("B" & lLastRow).Value = "NR"
    Range("C" & lLastRow).Value = "Name of Stock"
    Range("D" & lLastRow).Value = "PB"
    Range("E" & lLastRow).Value = "PA"
    Range("F" & lLastRow).Value = "PR"
    Range("H" & lLastRow).Value = "Name"
    Range("I" & lLastRow).Value = "1"
    Range("J" & lLastRow).Value = "2"
    Range("K" & lLastRow).Value = "3"
    Range("L" & lLastRow).Value = "4"
    Range("M" & lLastRow).Value = "5"
    Range("N" & lLastRow).Value = "Data"
    Range("B" & lLastRow + 1).Value = "1"
    Range("B" & lLastRow + 2).Value = "2"
    Range("B" & lLastRow + 3).Value = "3"
    Range("B" & lLastRow + 4).Value = "4"
    Range("B" & lLastRow + 5).Value = "5"
    Range("H" & lLastRow + 1).Value = "Price"
    Range("H" & lLastRow + 2).Value = "Price"
    Range("H" & lLastRow + 3).Value = "Price"
    Range("H" & lLastRow + 4).Value = "Price"
    Range("H" & lLastRow + 5).Value = "Price"
    lLastRow = lLastRow + 5
End Sub

Sub ResetStart()
    DoBorders Nothing
End Sub

Sub DoBorders(rng As Range)
Dim useRange        As Range
Static lastRange    As Range

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    'handle resetting the "last range"
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set lastRange = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Again, deleting rows (from 3 down), while testing, causes an error. So let's handle that.
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print lastRange.Row
    If Err.Number = 424 Then            ' If error, set lastRange to Nothing and all is OK.
        Set lastRange = Nothing
    End If
    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    If lastRange Is Nothing Then
        Set useRange = rng
    Else
        Set useRange = lastRange.Cells(1).Offset(lastRange.Rows.Count + 2, 0) _
                                   .Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    End If

    Set lastRange = useRange
    With useRange
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'remove all borders
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End With

    Exit Sub
Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
    Resume          ' For debugging
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Wayne. May I ask what is that Option Explicit, what dose it do?

Comment: VBA does not require you to explicitly declare variables that you work with in your code -- which can sometimes cause strange results. Say you have a line of code like: "MyTotal = 3 + 4", then later you want to check, but you forgot how you spelled it and you write "If MyTTL = 7 then" which will fail.   Using Option Explicit forces you to declare all variables.  Here is a good reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement